# How to stop the local port forwarding?

Tags: ssh, localhost, port-forwarding

I was trying local port forwarding and I hit the following command:

```
ssh -L 8080:www.ubuntuforums.org:80 <host>
```

in order to see what will happen. Now, on my computer, when I hit "http://localhost:8080" it redirects me to "http://www.canonical.com/".

I killed my ssh and checked my `/etc/hosts` file and the problem still exists. However, I have no clue how to disable it.

Two questions:

1. why it is redirected to canonical instead of ubuntuforums? how can I
2. stop this port forwarding?

Comment: Can you run `sudo ss -nltp` to see all programs listening on any port, and see if there is something that is listening on port 8080 (Apache, maybe)?

Comment: @saiarcot895 I did that and nobody is listening to port 8080.

Comment: You said "I killed my ssh." How? Usually you'd run `exit` in the remote shell and wait for the connection to terminate. Did that stall? Did you do it some other way? Once the SSH connection ends, nothing should forward through it. Could this be a browser quirk? What if you go to http://localhost:8080 in another browser? (If you don't have another one, try `wget http://localhost:8080` and check its output and the page downloaded, or try with the same browser run as different user without rebooting, e.g., Guest.) And when you reboot your computer, does that make localhost:8080 no longer forward?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem, except I was accessing a website from my university on port 8080 and was redirected to canonical.com.

It seems that canonical.com is set to port 8080 on Ubuntu computers at least as I can't access any other website on that port whether or not I'm port tunnelling. I don't know how to stop this but try tunnelling on any other port ( ex. port: 9000 ) and it should work perfectly while you're logged in and then stop when you log out.

Comment: Then this is a very serious issue, is that right?

Comment: @emab what do you mean by serious issue?

Comment: Why should canonical set its web site to port 8080? That's a security issue I think

Comment: Not sure why they would do that, but as they develop ubuntu I'm not overly concerned. However, if anyone knows why they do this, or how to stop this from happening, I would love to know.